# How to detect missing arguments in decorator?

Tags: python, exception, decorator, python-decorators

I would like to define a decorator with a parameter that raises an error if the parameter is missing.

Here's a naive attempt on a simplified example:

```
def decorator_with_arg(a=None):

    if a is None :
        raise ValueError("Missing argument in decorator")

    def decorator(func):

        def wrapped_func(x):
            return func(x+ a)

        return wrapped_func

    return decorator
```

But when I use this decorator without a parameter it's not raising any errors:

```
@decorator_with_arg
def simple_func(x):
    return 2*x

simple_func(1)
```

How can I raise an exception?

Comment: And if you remove the default `=None`, and let the compiler raise the error? Because now, you'll raise your own error during runtime. Also, if a user explicitly passes `None` as the argument, but there actually is an argument, your code will still raise an error.

Comment: This is what I did at first, but in the real code forgetting to call the decorator with the parameter  was not triggering any errors, which I believe is a bit dangerous, hence the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not using your decorator correctly, in your code `simple_func(1)` will just return `wrapped_func`, because `@decorator_with_arg` will simply do:

```
simple_func = decorator_with_arg(simple_func)
#                                ^ this is passing a=simple_func
# now simple_func is the decorator function defined inside decorator_with_arg
```

You need to *call* your `decorator_with_arg` in order for it to return `decorator` which will then be used to decorate the function:

```
@decorator_with_arg(100)
def simple_func(x):
    return 2*x

print(simple_func(1)) # 202
```

In any case, if you want to make an argument mandatory, simply declare it without a default value:

```
def decorator_with_arg(a):
    # ...
```

And remove the `if a is None` check.

---

If you want to avoid mistakes in using `@decorator_with_arg` instead of `@decorator_with_arg()`, you can add a check to ensure `a` is not a function:

```
def decorator_with_arg(a):
    if callable(a):
        raise TypeError("Incorrect use of decorator")
    
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapped_func(x):
            return func(x + a)
        return wrapped_func
    return decorator


@decorator_with_arg
def func():
    return 1
# TypeError: Incorrect use of decorator


@decorator_with_arg(123)
def func():
    return 1
# All fine
```